# Row_number() combined with missing data (NA) in dataset

Tags: r

I have the following df:

```
car <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors = FALSE, year = c(2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,2011,2012,2013,2014,2015), 
                       person = c("A","A","A","A","A","A", "B","B","B","B","B","B","C","C","C","C","C"),
                       car = c("BMW", "BMW", "AUDI", "AUDI", "AUDI", "Mercedes", "Citroen","Citroen", "Citroen", "Toyota", "Toyota", "Peugeot", "Volkswagen","Volkswagen","Mercedes", "Mercedes","Tesla"))
```

Im trying to reproduce this (i. e. creating the how_long_does_the_person_have_the_car variable)

```
   car <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors = FALSE, year = c(2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,2011,2012,2013,2014,2015), 
                       person = c("A","A","A","A","A","A", "B","B","B","B","B","B","C","C","C","C","C"),
                       car = c("BMW", "BMW", "AUDI", "AUDI", "AUDI", "Mercedes", "Citroen","Citroen", "Citroen", "Toyota", "Toyota", "Peugeot", "Volkswagen","Volkswagen","Mercedes", "Mercedes","Tesla"),
                       how_long_does_the_person_have_the_car = c(1,2,1,2,3,1,1,2,3,1,2,1,"0/NA", "0/NA", 1,2,1))


tibble::tribble(
~year, ~person, ~car, ~how_long_does_the_person_have_the_car,
2010, "A", "BMW", "1",
2011, "A", "BMW", "2",
2012, "A", "AUDI", "1",
2013, "A", "AUDI", "2",
2014, "A", "AUDI", "3",
2015, "A", "Mercedes", "1",
2010, "B", "Citroen", "1",
2011, "B", "Citroen", "2",
2012, "B", "Citroen", "3",
2013, "B", "Toyota", "1",
2014, "B", "Toyota", "2",
2015, "B", "Peugeot", "1",
2011, "C", "Volkswagen", "0/NA",
2012, "C", "Volkswagen", "0/NA",
2013, "C", "Mercedes", "1",
2014, "C", "Mercedes", "2",
2015, "C", "Tesla", "1"
```

The how_long_does_the_person_have_the_car variable is a cumulative sum of the variable car, and gets resetted everytime the car or person changes. The problem is that when i use this formula:

```
car <- car %>% 
   group_by(person, car) %>% 
   mutate( how_long_does_the_person_have_the_car = row_number())
```

I get this output:

```
tibble::tribble(
~year, ~person, ~car, ~how_long_does_the_person_have_the_car,
2010, "A", "BMW", 1,
2011, "A", "BMW", 2,
2012, "A", "AUDI", 1,
2013, "A", "AUDI", 2,
2014, "A", "AUDI", 3,
2015, "A", "Mercedes", 1,
2010, "B", "Citroen", 1,
2011, "B", "Citroen", 2,
2012, "B", "Citroen", 3,
2013, "B", "Toyota", 1,
2014, "B", "Toyota", 2,
2015, "B", "Peugeot", 1,
2011, "C", "Volkswagen", 1,
2012, "C", "Volkswagen", 2,
2013, "C", "Mercedes", 1,
2014, "C", "Mercedes", 2,
2015, "C", "Tesla", 1
)
```

However, as i am missing data from 2010 for person C, i would like to have for 2011 & 2012 for person C a value of 0 or NA or something else, as the data from 2010 is missing, and we do not know if person C has his/her Volkswagen for 1 or 2 years in 2011/2012, or for 2/3 years, as we do not know which car person C had in 2010. In 2013, the cumulative value can start counting from 1 again, as now we now that in 2013 person C bought a Mercedes instead.

Comment: If that's all your data, why not replacing by hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution can be to complete the years by declaring the row number as NA and use that to replace the values, i.e.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

car %>% 
   group_by(person, car) %>%
   mutate(res = row_number()) %>% 
   ungroup() %>%
   complete(year, person) %>% 
   arrange(person, year, car) %>% 
   fill(car, .direction = 'updown') %>%
   group_by(person, car) %>%
   mutate(res1 = replace(res, any(is.na(res)), NA)) %>%
   filter(!is.na(res)) %>%
   select(-res)

# A tibble: 17 x 4
# Groups:   person, car [9]
    year person car         res1
   <dbl> <chr>  <chr>      <int>
 1  2010 A      BMW            1
 2  2011 A      BMW            2
 3  2012 A      AUDI           1
 4  2013 A      AUDI           2
 5  2014 A      AUDI           3
 6  2015 A      Mercedes       1
 7  2010 B      Citroen        1
 8  2011 B      Citroen        2
 9  2012 B      Citroen        3
10  2013 B      Toyota         1
11  2014 B      Toyota         2
12  2015 B      Peugeot        1
13  2011 C      Volkswagen    NA
14  2012 C      Volkswagen    NA
15  2013 C      Mercedes       1
16  2014 C      Mercedes       2
17  2015 C      Tesla          1
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible option:

```r
library(tidyverse)

car <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE, year = c(2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015),
  person = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C"),
  car = c("BMW", "BMW", "AUDI", "AUDI", "AUDI", "Mercedes", "Citroen", "Citroen", "Citroen", "Toyota", "Toyota", "Peugeot", "Volkswagen", "Volkswagen", "Mercedes", "Mercedes", "Tesla")
)

car |> 
  mutate(min_year = min(year)) |> 
  group_by(person, car) |> 
  mutate(how_long = row_number()) |> 
  group_by(person) |> 
  mutate(
    first_car = first(car),
    how_long = if_else(first(year) > min_year & car == first_car, NA_integer_, how_long)
    ) |> 
  select(-first_car)
#> # A tibble: 17 × 5
#> # Groups:   person [3]
#>     year person car        min_year how_long
#>    <dbl> <chr>  <chr>         <dbl>    <int>
#>  1  2010 A      BMW            2010        1
#>  2  2011 A      BMW            2010        2
#>  3  2012 A      AUDI           2010        1
#>  4  2013 A      AUDI           2010        2
#>  5  2014 A      AUDI           2010        3
#>  6  2015 A      Mercedes       2010        1
#>  7  2010 B      Citroen        2010        1
#>  8  2011 B      Citroen        2010        2
#>  9  2012 B      Citroen        2010        3
#> 10  2013 B      Toyota         2010        1
#> 11  2014 B      Toyota         2010        2
#> 12  2015 B      Peugeot        2010        1
#> 13  2011 C      Volkswagen     2010       NA
#> 14  2012 C      Volkswagen     2010       NA
#> 15  2013 C      Mercedes       2010        1
#> 16  2014 C      Mercedes       2010        2
#> 17  2015 C      Tesla          2010        1
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score -2):

I'm a bit confused by your problem, as you already have the cumulutative number of years the cars are owned, with some missing data. Is it not enought to just convert the missing data to explicit **NA's** ?

```
car$how_long_does_the_person_have_the_car[
  car$how_long_does_the_person_have_the_car == '0/NA'
] <- NA
```

You will then have the desired output you want. If it is necessary to cumulate/rank these again, you can rank by the ownership variable (Assuming it is there already), but this will just give you the same result:

```
car <- car %>%  #This is assuming explicit NA's in ranking variable
  group_by(person, car) %>% 
  mutate(how_long_does_the_person_have_the_car = row_number(how_long_does_the_person_have_the_car)) #Rank by column
```

Both of these give the same output:

```
# A tibble: 17 × 4
# Groups:   person, car [9]
    year person car        how_long_does_the_person_have_the_car
   <dbl> <chr>  <chr>                                      <int>
 1  2010 A      BMW                                            1
 2  2011 A      BMW                                            2
 3  2012 A      AUDI                                           1
 4  2013 A      AUDI                                           2
 5  2014 A      AUDI                                           3
 6  2015 A      Mercedes                                       1
 7  2010 B      Citroen                                        1
 8  2011 B      Citroen                                        2
 9  2012 B      Citroen                                        3
10  2013 B      Toyota                                         1
11  2014 B      Toyota                                         2
12  2015 B      Peugeot                                        1
13  2011 C      Volkswagen                                    NA
14  2012 C      Volkswagen                                    NA
15  2013 C      Mercedes                                       1
16  2014 C      Mercedes                                       2
17  2015 C      Tesla                                          1
```

Comment: I think you mixed the expected output with the actual data

Comment: Yes i must have misunderstood the problem. Sorry about that.